# Removing all instances of Nexcess / Turpentine

Tags: cache, varnish, enterprise-1.14, turpentine

I have 4 stores and I was successfully able to remove it from all stores except one of them. When i remove the last folder from my problem store i throw some system.log errors.

```
public_html/var/log/system.log:1549:2015-10-09T16:02:32+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Nexcessnet/Turpentine/Model/PageCache/Container/Notices.php' for inclusion (include_path='/public_html/app/code/local:/public_html/app/code/community:/public_html/app/code/core:/public_html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
./public_html/var/log/system.log:1550:2015-10-09T16:02:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Nexcessnet/Turpentine/Model/PageCache/Container/Notices.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

I'm able to successfully remove all the other files/folders from my other stores. They throw the same error in my system.log but the stores are still up and running. This store on the other hand it shows just a blank page, I still see the favicon in the tab so i guess it looks like it wants to load but nothing.

Comment: Do you have compilation enabled? Have you stopped Varnish and reconfigured the ports?

Comment: I do not have compilation enabled. I'm pretty sure I've stopped varnish because I've removed all instances of it on the web server. Maybe i missed something? Also, i'm not 100% sure about the ports so i'm going to say I have not and this is something that i may have overlooked. What ports should i be looking for and where would i go to look and/or adjust if necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Varnish usually sits in front of apache, which means port 80 is used by Varnish and you reconfigure apache to listen to another port (8080 most of the time).

Comment: I was running varnish on my aws server but have since migrated to rackspace which is why i'm trying to remove it completely. I'm not using apache on rackspace but rather nginx, so there should be no problem then, ehhh?

Comment: For what is worth, replace the word apache with nginx and the same should apply when talking about a traditional varnish+webserver approach.

Comment: All 4 of my websites are already listening to port 80 but none of them are having a problem except this one particular website. Are you saying change this one website to port 8080? It's the only website that still has a nexcessnet folder in the directory but when i delete it the entire website goes blank. Just wanted to reiterate the problem to ensure were on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

if you sure you have all caches deleted, then you need to search once again like:

```
updatedb
locate -i turpentine

cd /path/to/magento/app/
grep "turpentine" -i -r *
```

and probably you have some custom changes or cache.

Comment: Have you fixed this? find . | xargs grep 'Turpentine' -sl might be useful too to find Turpentine occurrences, run it fro your Magento root folder.